# Open a new window using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any way to open a new window or new tab using PHP without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, a window can only be opening by adding `target="_blank"` attribute (invalid in Strict (X)HTML, but valid in HTML5) or using JavaSript's `window.open(url '_blank')`.

PHP runs server side - therefore it can generate the HTML or JavaScript, but it can't directly interact with the client.

Comment: the `target` attribute *is* valid in XHTML, so long as you use the Transitional doctype. Similarly, it's invalid in HTML if you're using the Strict doctype

Comment: @Gareth Thanks will make an amendment.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **No**.

PHP is a [server side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) (at least in the context of web development). It has absolutely no control over the client side, i.e. the browser.

Answer (score 3):

No. PHP is a server-side language, meaning that it is completely done with its work before the browser has even started rendering the page. You need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP is server-side scripting

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language, it's what produces all the code you see on a page when you choose *View Source*. PHP cannot affect the client on its own, it needs to do it through a language such as JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side, as everyone states, however you can add a `target="_blank"` attribute to your form tag. This doesn't perform any work server side, but does let you submit the form to a new window to be processed on the server.

A neat trick, but 1) deprecated in HTML Strict and 2) rarely useful.

Comment: The only people that think that is useful are naive clients that think it will keep users on *their* website (there are a few defensible exceptions, however). +1 for *rarely useful*.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is dedicated to the [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php) thread; you can execute this block of code:

```
<?php
   echo "<script> window.open(\"about:blank\"); </script>";
?>
```

Hopefully this helps!