# How to show error as alert box in PHP

Tags: php

I want to show error as window browser alert
like - [Click Here](https://www.royaliker.net/index.php?i=Username/Password%20was%20wrong.%20Try%20again.)

But i want to use URL 
as - [Click Here](http://www.hubliker.com/?code=100)
Is there any way to use?
I Have Code Below:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['i'])){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO:  ' . $_GET['i'] . '");</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Code looks fine for what it's trying to do - is it not working?

Comment: You can use a case statement (or any other type of control structure) inside your `if` statement to output the correct error message - based on the error code in the URL. Other pages can simply redirect to this main page with the correct ID in the URL or headers.

Comment: It Is Working But i want URL Like http://royaliker.net/?i=100

Comment: @SukhchainSingh: I see alert in link you post in comment above. Maybe cache?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246318/can-i-add-a-javascript-alert-inside-a-php-function-if-yes-how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the message depending on your error code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['i'])){
        switch($_GET['i']) {
            case 100:
                $errorMsg = "Please use a valid email"; // For example
            break;
            case 200:
                $errorMsg = "Email already in use";
            break;
            default:
                // If $_GET['i'] has an unexpected value
                $errorMsg = "Oops, there was an unknown error";
            break;
        }
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO:  '.$errorMsg.'");</script>';
    }
?>
```