# What are Extensions in php v8js?

Tags: php, javascript, v8, pecl

I have started using v8js with php for a while now but the documentation is really thin.

One thing that is not explained is *Extensions*.

It is possible to [registerExtension](http://php.net/manual/en/v8js.registerextension.php) but it is not explained in detail how these behave or whats their purpose or benefits.

Can anyone provide a good description or link to a documentation that explains Extensions?

Thanks to everyone for taking time to read and answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Original Answer**

My original answer indicated that the extension was called every time `executeString` was.

**Corrected answer**

An extension is a bit of code that is executed before the first `executeString` call for a given V8Js instance.
Extension can be global to all V8Js instances or local to a specific instance.

I have experimentally determined that this isn't always very reliable. If you frantically refresh a page, you may not always see the extension get run... This is probably why this is beta quality software.

Here are two examples that I whipped up

### Global Extension Example

**Code**

```
V8Js::registerExtension('say_hi', 'print("hey from extension! "); var said_hi=true;', array(), true);
$v8 = new V8Js();
$v8->executeString('print("hello from regular code!")', 'test.php');
$v8->executeString('if (said_hi) { print(" extension already said hi"); }');
```

**Output**

> hey from extension! hello from regular code! extension already said hi

### Non-Global Example

**Code**

```
V8Js::registerExtension('say_hi', 'print("hey from non global extension! "); var said_hi=true;');
$v8 = new V8Js('PHP', array(), array('say_hi'));
$v8->executeString('print("hello from regular code!");', 'test.php');
$v8->executeString('if (said_hi) { print(" extension already said hi"); }');
```

**Output**

> hey from non global extension! hello from regular code! extension already said hi

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried the examples. In the global example it is only executed once, all subsequent calls on executeString did not execute the extension code again.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I've updated my answer to reflect that :)