# How to call a javascript function in a php web page?

Tags: php, javascript, function, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

I have a php page in which I echo certain things depending on the user privilege (admin or user). I would like to know if I can call a javascript function when a button is clicked.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['access_rights']=='admin') {
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $userName = $_GET['username'];
     echo "<a href='../view/confirmDelete.php?id=$id&type=task&username=$userName'><input type='button' class='delete-btn' value=''/></a>
           <a href='../view/editTask.php?id=$id&username=$userName'><input type='submit' class='edit-btn' value=''/></a>";
}
?>
```

The function I would like to call is as follows. This is placed in the head of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteTask(id,task,name) {
    var conBox = confirm("Are you sure you wanna delete task assigned to "+ name + " ?");
    if (conBox) {
        location.href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
</script>
```

I was wondering if the function 'deleteTask()' can be called via a href like

```
<a href="javascript" deleteTask('<?=id;?>','task','<?=userName?>');">Delete me</a>
```

else using onclick="deleteTask();

I am required to pass arguments to the function. I am unable to the javascript call in href as it requires quote. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the quotes directly after `javascript` you close the `href`-attribute. Use a `:` to seperate the keyword `javascript` and the command:

In PHP (don't forget to escape the quotes):

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:deleteTask('$id;','task','$userName');\">Delete me</a>";
```

or HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteTask('<?=$id?>','task','<?=$userName?>');">Delete me</a>
```

Comment: No it wont work as I'm echoing the 'a href'. So the quotes are a problem

Comment: The answer is    
    echo "<a href='../router/confirmDelete.php?id=$id&username=$userName'><input type='button' class='delete-btn' value='' onclick='return deleteTask()'/></a>
                                        <a href='../view/editTask.php?id=$id&username=$userName'><input type='submit' class='edit-btn' value=''/></a>";


and change the script accordingly.

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteTask() {
        var conBox = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (conBox) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Click Here' onclick='deleteTask(id, task, name)' />"
```

Comment: No, this post did not serve my purpose, but rather the first one did. Thanks any how.