# How to load javascript contents using php?

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

How to load javascript contents using php. Suppose when php saves a file using, file get contents and file put contents, JavaScript contents like Google current ads is never loaded but the google adsense codes are loaded.

Can php "run" the JavaScript code on a saved page in order to save the dynamic content that the code generates?
Already got the answer is NO.
Is there any way or no Way?

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: PHP cannot by itself execute javascript. You can parse HTML to extract `<script>` tags and fetch any remote scripts specified in the `src=` attribute, but again... PHP won't execute the JS code.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether or not PHP can "run" the JavaScript code on a saved page in order to save the dynamic content that the code generates. The answer is no, it cannot. Or at least, not without building your own JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: Yes. You got my point. As php can't do the job, is there any way out there? Any other language or extension.

Comment: Not a specific language, no. But you might be able to use a GUI-less (headless) browser to render the page: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ and then capture the resulting markup

Comment: @SimpleCoder: it recently got covered in proggit and HN, but looking at it more closely it seems to be older than that: http://pecl.php.net/package/v8js

Comment: @SimpleCoder Hope you won't mind if i ask, Why JavaScript shows such a behavior. To increase Security or ...?