# Calling javascript from php

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have setup an overlay script to enable me to display an overlay popup so to speak, it works great, because i cna call it from a button etc... However i want to be able to see if the user has come to the page with a subid present in their header, if not, then i want the overlay to appear.

Here is the code where the overlay needs to be called from

```
    if (isset($_GET['eid'])) {


 if ($_GET['eid'] == ""){
 // CALL THE overlay_choose_house from here
 } else{
     $estate_id = $_GET['eid'];
 }

}
```

Here is the code that is being called

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#overlay_choose_house').bind('click', function(event){
    if (event.target == $('#overlay_choose_house').get(0))
        overlay_choose_house(); 
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#overlay_choose_house').bind('click', function(event){
            if (event.target == $('#overlay_choose_house').get(0))
            overlay_choose_house(); 
        });

        <?php if ($_GET['eid'] == ""){ ?>overlay_choose_house();<?php } ?>

    });
```

Or this, replace:

```
// CALL THE overlay_choose_house from here
```

with

```
$x = true;
```

and than, as before:

```
<?php if ($x){ ?>overlay_choose_house();<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ok great, i modified your code a little, but i managed to make it work, thanks for giving me your ideas.