# Clear input text after executing some PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       $sent = mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers) ;

       if($sent)
       {
        echo '<script> cleartext(); </script>';
       }

    }
?>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function cleartext()
    {
         alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
         document.getElementById('name').value = '';
         document.getElementById('email').value = '';
         document.getElementById('phone').value = '';
         document.getElementById('message').value = '';

         alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
    }
</script>
```

**Source Code :**

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="margin-bottom" target="hidden" id="contact">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6  col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name*" id="name" name="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6  col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email*" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone*" id="phone" maxlength="13" name="phone" />
      </div>
  </div>

<textarea placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="clear" name="clear" class="button" value="Clear &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" onClick="cleartext();">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','email','','RisEmail','phone','','RisNum','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">

</form>
```

**Problem**

I want to clear all input text after sending a mail on submit.on submit I am calling `cleartext()` from my `PHP` code.but on that time I am not being able to clear my input text value.And when I call `cleartext()` method on clear button it's works proper.if somebody have idea about it so please help me.

Comment: Why two `submit` buttons?

Comment: it's client requirement he want two submit button.First one Clear and second one is Submit.on clear button it clear all input text and on submit button he send email.

Comment: Tried `form.reset();`?

Answer (score 0):

You missed script type. that might be the problem.

```
<?php
 //stuff to do
 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
 cleartext();  
 </script>';
?>
```

see this [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Comment: sorry buddy but it's not issue of `type="text/javascript"`.my code is also running but my problem is that i am not being able to clear value of input text.

Answer (score 0):

For button to clear fields, use type "reset" instead of "submit"

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

And to clear the fields after submit, try redirecting

```
if($sent) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put a setTimeout in the onClick of the js function that clear the form

```
 <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" onClick="setTimeout( MM_validateForm, 1000 )" >
```

Answer (score -1):

you using submit button for clear, it shouldn't work because the form will be submitting its values
and the way is you should make it return `false` in `onclick` in order to prevent submitting form.
your code should be like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="clear" name="clear" class="button" value="Clear &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" onClick="cleartext(); return false;">
```

Comment: And if something failed in PHP your entries are always nulled? That's not nice :)

Comment: @Eko Dedy sorry budy but i want to call `cleartext()` from my php code on submit button

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $sent = mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers) ;

   if($sent) $b_sent = true;

}
```

Javascript:

```
function cleartext()
{
     alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
     document.getElementById('name').value = '';
     document.getElementById('email').value = '';
     document.getElementById('phone').value = '';
     document.getElementById('message').value = '';

     alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
}
var bClear = <?= $b_sent? 'true':'false' ?>;
if (bClear) cleartext();
```