# Why is my javascript function not being called in my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I want a div to just call a function(not move my position on the page) but instead of calling my JavaScript function - it moves my location on the page

what am I doing wrong? (running inside of joomla)

Why is my JavaScript function not being called in my div?

```
http://....com/test.php#p3


<div id="p1" onclick="testFunction()"> 
</div>

<div id="p3">Some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   testFunction();
</script>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


function testFunction() {
   alert("Test");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to place those `script` tags above that `div`.

Comment: What do you mean by "called in my div"? Functions aren't related to any specific DOM element.

Comment: the only problem I can see the `testFunction` is called in a script block before it is declared in another script

Comment: it should throw an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined `

Comment: Are you talking about `#p3` in the URL? The meaning of a hash in the URL is to scroll to that element.

Comment: moving them fixed it - why is this? -

Comment: @Barmar - is there a way to use a div to call a function and NOT move the page?

Comment: because when the first script bock is executed the function is not yet created because that script block in which the function is defined is yet to be executed...

Comment: `<script>` blocks are loaded one at a time. When you load the first block, the second block hasn't been loaded yet, so the function isn't defined.

Comment: You can write a script that looks at `window.location.hash` and does what you want. Then it can call `scrollTo` to scroll to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two separate script blocks, the first one calling the function defined in the second one. Put them into one single block and it will work.

```
<div id="p1" onclick="testFunction()">click me</div>
<div id="p3">Some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
testFunction();
function testFunction() {
    alert("Test");
}
</script>
```

Comments saying you need to define it at the top are not true, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xDf5e/

They would be true if you defined a variable function like: `var testFunction = function(...`. Generally, you should define functions at the top of your JS blocks, it makes the code more readable and maintanable, but that's not the reason your script is not working.

Note: you can see the onclick works fine as well in the example I gave you.

You have a nice tutorial about function hoisting here: http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/

Answer (score -1):

Testfunction should be defined first before use

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function testFunction() {
        alert("Test");
  }
 </script>
 <div id="p1" onclick="testFunction()"> 
 </div>
 <div id="p3">Some content</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   testFunction();
 </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: That's not true, see my answer. It would be true if you defined a variable like: `var testFunction = function(...`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. But my solution does also work as i tested before i posted

Comment: It does work, of course, but it doesn't answer the question ('Why...?').

Comment: I explained. According to the original problem, author has 2 different script blocks and testfunction() is called in one script block before its declaration in another block. Your solution is right because you call and define function in one script block. I do not think i deserve a down vote.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my answer says. Sorry, I didn't see your explanation.

Comment: So, if "Testfunction should be defined first before use", it would work. And i think i will stop comment from here as it would go nowhere. The problem has been solved, that is the main point. Thanks