# Run php script within javascript <script> in .php file?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to run a php script within a javascript `<script>` in a .php file. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$("#id").example("
    <?php print('Hello World'); ?>
");

</script>
```

Comment: javascript only supports single line literal strings.

Comment: He's saying that you need it to be on one line, like this:

$("#id").example("<?php print('Hello World'); ?>");

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. JavaScript is (unless you use node.JS) running in you WebBrowser. php get's started by your apache webserver when the webserver gets an http request for example to `http://localhost/test.php`. So these two scripts run in two completely different scopes. If you want to start a php file (called REST-Service) you need to perform an ajax-request:

JQuery style: (I don't like it but anyway...)

```
$.ajax({url:"myTestFile.php",success:function(result){
    $("#id").html(result);
}});
```

Best regards

Dustin

Comment: Ok, so would this AJAX method be the recommended way to use a php tag for a CMS content field within javascript/jquery? (For example if you needed to give a user the ability to upload photos to a jquery image gallery?)

Comment: When you want to load your data asynchronous after loading the page there is no other way to do this. So I would recommend it. However you should weigh up if you really need asynchronous loading of data, because search engines cannot find this data. So you will not get a good rank in google.

Comment: No need for asynchronous data in this case, and I've got it working. It appeared to be down to javascript not accepting multi-line strings. It's always the simple things!

Answer (score 0):

This examples shows you how you can pass $variable from php to Javascript

```
<?php $x = 'hello world'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var str = '<?php print("Hello World"); ?>' ;
    $("#id").html(str);

</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of print, you can use echo and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#id").example("
    <?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
");
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

It Will help you.You can add php code in single quote. Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="id">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$("#id").text('<?="Hello World"?>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```