# Call Javascript function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to call a javascript function and use the results(Json) as variable for PHP.
I have the following function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script>        
        $(function () {
            
            var baseUrl = 'https://XXXXXXXXX/';
            var uid = 'XXXX';
            var pwd = 'XXXX';
                        
            
            GetProd('DT.X0CEB.009', '1');

           function GetProd(cod_prod, qtd) {
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl + 'api/Prod?ref=' + encodeURIComponent(cod_prod) + '&qtd=' + qtd,
                    type: 'GET',
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    username: uid,
                    password: pwd,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        document.write(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                   }
            });
        }
    });            
    </script>
```

This returns this:

> Object { Ref: "DT.X0CEB.009", Desc: "Monitor UltraHD P2715Q  68.6cm
>   27"", State: 0, Price: Object, Tax: Object, Stock: 2, Availability:
>   null }

Can anybody help me how to use this fields (ref, desc, state, ...)in php?
Regards
Pedro

Comment: Unless you have a JavaScript engine **on the server** that you can call from PHP (which is possible, but complicated and probably not what you're really trying to do), you can't do this. Let's think through the steps: 1. User requests a page. 2. The server gets the request and runs the PHP, generating an HTML file to return. 3. That file goes back to the client. 4. The client runs any JavaScript code on the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 1):

You are sending them as GET params therefore they should be available in your endpoint via $_GET. You could also try sending a data object via POST and retrieve them with $_POST in your php API.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourUrl',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //do something with data
  }
});

PHP

$param1 = $_POST['param1'];
$param2 = $_POST['param2'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the awswer but I didn't get it, in the function(data) i have document.write(data);. To get the variables i should use $data=$_GET['data']; in PHP?

Comment: no, PHP is processed on the server, you will need to post back to PHP again if you want to process the results of the call. I would send another ajax request on success and include the results of the first call.