# Call A Java Script Function From C# Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am attempting to populate a html page by passing in values using `QueryString` and my values are passing in the `QueryString` but my limited to **NO** knowledge of JS is preventing me from being able to deduce why the textbox on the page isn't populating with the passed value.

**This is my HTML showing the JS Function**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject.Pages.Test" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeaderID" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<div class="BackgroundOfWhite">
    <font class="BB">Select Instructor:</font>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdown1" 
AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="DropDownLists" ></asp:DropDownList>    
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOpenPage" 
CssClass="Buttons" Text="Open Page With Params" OnClick="btnLoadPage_Click" />
    <div class="White"></div>        
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('InstructorName').value = Instructor;
</script>
```

**This is my C# info here**

```
protected void btnLoadPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string openthis = "http://whiskeyinthewatertestofsendingdata.html";
    string Instructor = "Tyler Moore";
    Response.Redirect(openthis+"?"+Instructor);
}
```

I feel that the issue is I am not actually calling the JS function to populate the textbox on the hmtl page, but how would I do such?

**EDIT:**
This is the html behind the textbox

```
<input id="InstructorName" name="InstructorName" maxlength="255" style="width: 240px;">
```

**EDIT 2**
I see this 1st few lines of HTML of the page...does this mean on the page load they force the fields to have a null value (which of course would mean their is no way to achieve what I am after)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var forcefieldstonull = 
 {
 "InstructorName":null,
  "InstructorClass":null,
  "InstructorBuilding":null,
  "InstructorRoomNum":null
};
```

Comment: It's not the same answer exactly so I won't report you, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php

Comment: `"http://whiskeyinthewatertestofsendingdata.html";` hopefully that isn't the real URL that you are trying to use...

Comment: @RonBeyer - no it is not the real URL just threw a garbage URL in their for the ? purpose

Comment: @user2754599 When you flag as a duplicate, you are not reporting the user (which makes it sound like the user has done something very bad). Instead, you are flagging *the question*.

Comment: In response to Edit 2: not necessarily. There may be some code afterwards that checks the URL. You'll have to look and see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected void btnLoadPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string openthis = "http://whiskeyinthewatertestofsendingdata.html";
    string Instructor = "Tyler Moore";
    Response.Redirect(openthis+"?Instructor="+Instructor);
}
```

and then, on your page, change your javascript function to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('InstructorName').value = '<%=Request.QueryString["Instructor"]%>';
</script>
```

Comment: That is not populating the textbox on the page with the value of Instructor

Comment: Well, where's your '<input type="text" id="InstructorName" />'  ??

Comment: @mason that would be the case if he was using an <asp:TextBox> element, but it's just a simple <input type="text" /> that has no runat="server"

Comment: @RashidAbib go for the basics: before the ''document.getElementById'', do a simple javascript alert. Include this line: `alert('Instructor: ' + '<%=Request.QueryString["Instructor"]%>');`

Comment: the alert is fired on the page that launches btn_pageLoad() never on the openthis page.

Comment: @RashidAbib The JavaScript code needs to go on the receiving page, the page the user gets redirected to.

Comment: @RashidAbib Then you won't be able to accomplish what you want to do. Unless that page is already set up to receive parameters via the URL somehow or has some other mechanism of prepopulating fields, you can't do that from a redirect. Why can't you edit? Is the page on a 3rd party site?

Comment: @Mason - yes it is a 3rd party site.  Was attempting to auto-populate data from our database into the 3rd party site as opposed to it having to manually be entered one by one

Comment: @RashidAbib In that case, you'll have to inspect their HTML source code to see if they might have something on the client side that can pull values out of the URL. Or check and see if they have an API you can use. And lastly, you may be able to contact the website operators to see if something exists or if they could add something for you.

Comment: @Mason - what in the page HTML would be an indicator that they are set-up to pull values from the URL?

Comment: @RashidAbib It would be in the JavaScript. You'd see it inspecting the URL, there might be some checks on `window.location` or `$.url` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the page to be loaded completely before you can change it's elements.
Though the javascript is at the bottom it comes to my mind that it might be executed before the InstructorName div is rendered.

You should surround it with window.onload() to make sure that it is executed after the page is fully loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Additionally what you can do is simply check the Browsers console if the script gives you an error.

Comment: I used the window.onload tip in the link you provided and still no luck.  The textbox is not being populated.  How would I check the Browser Console?

Comment: Use Firefox Chrome or even Internet Explorer and press F12.

Comment: I let the page load, and hit f12 and the console window is empty

Comment: Are you sure your server side passes the value of "Instructor " (I'm guessing its a variable in C#?) in the html the client gets? What I mean is, if you check the source code of the webpage and scroll down to the script part - is the value you want in the textbox actually there?

Comment: If I step through my code, Instructor has a value, and it is displayed in the QueryString in the URL of the page also.

Comment: When you answered I was editing the last sentence in my last comment: What I mean is, if you check the source code (rightclick somewhere on the page -> show source code) of the webpage and scroll down to the script part - is the value you want in the textbox actually there?

Comment: No - I do not see my value mentioned anywhere when I click on View Page Source.  I see the field name InstructorName but not the value I am attempting to fill the textfield with.

Comment: @RashidAbib When you look at the page HTML and you don't see the value filled, what is the URL?

Comment: The URL shows the passed value http://whiskeyinthewatertestofsendingdata.html?Instructor=Tyler%20Moore