# Setting setInterval timer from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am stuck on very simple thing, but i can't seem to google it out or figure it out, so i'm out of solutions.

```
   setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility= hidden ? "hidden" : "hidden";
    hidden = !hidden;
    document.getElementById("gifuser").style.visibility= hidden ? "hidden" : "hidden";
    hidden = !hidden;

    var aT = function animationTime(animTIME){

        return aT;
    };

},aT)
```

This is my code right now. I want to make 4000 a variable, that is defined by PHP.

That is the code that is being made by PHP (it runs after the first one, if this helps):

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">animationTime("'.$row['animTIME'].'");</script>';
```

I understand what is happening, which is:
variable animTIME or aT stays inside functions scope. 
How to make it global, so setInterval function would know it.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following

```
var animationTime = <?php echo $row['animTIME']; ?>;
//etc...
setInterval(function(){
      //...
},animationTime);
//...
setInterval(function(){
      //...
},animationTime/*2*/);
```

Your code is not really clean, you should set the var values outside of functions scopes in this case.