# IF statement in PHP code

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table

I have a code that will display data in a table form.
there is a field called value that will store some values.
I need to have an if statement that will force a window to popup whenever the value exceeds 30. I have an if statement that is not working. Can anyone help?

This is the code I used:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$select= mysql_select_db("");
mysql_select_db("form");


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY parameter ASC");
$record = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo "<table border=1
<tr>
<th>Record ID</th>
<th>Parameter</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Time</th>

</tr>";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
//$query = "select * from demo";

$query1 = mysql_query("Select * from demo where parameter = \"conductivity\"");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

        echo " <tr><td>" . $row["recordID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["parameter"] . "</td><td>" . $row["value"] . "</td><td>" . $row["time"]  . "</td><tr>";

    }

if ("value">"30"){
echo "<script>alert('Alert');</script>";
}



echo "</table>";



mysql_close($link);



?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Comment: you need to bin the mysql driver, its gone in PHP7 and horrible before that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surrely it needs to be like this within the while loop presuming by value you mean the value from the `SELECT` statement. Which means you need `$row["value"]` and not just `"value"`. Javascript in php just work like any other string would so echo it out like you've done inside the `if`.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    echo " <tr><td>" . $row["recordID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["parameter"] . "</td><td>" . $row["value"] . "</td><td>" . $row["time"]  . "</td><tr>";

    if ($row["value"] > 30){
        echo "<script>alert('Alert');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question you should mark it as such!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition that you're using to this:

```
if ($row["value"] > 30) {
    echo "<script>alert('Alert');</script>";
}
```

The condition was checking the string with a value of "value" against "30".  Checking the field value should be better.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the
`if ("value">"30")`.

the `value` should be a variable loop from the database.

declare a variable called `$value` before the loop.

And in the loop

`$query1 = mysql_query("Select * from demo where parameter = \"conductivity\"");`
`$value;`
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){`

`$value = $value + ~$row['value'];`

`//Assuming that value is the name of the column in your table`

`}`