# Javascript code not working inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php

This is the code I am executing inside PHP condition

```
<?php
    if(is_null($model)) {
        echo "<script>window.parent.closeIframe(true)</script>";
    }
?>
```

It doesn't work even If I put alert or calling a function inside my PHP condition.

Is it possible to run a Javascript code inside PHP ? 
Is there any PHP extensions needed to be enabled ?

Comment: php is run at server side, javascript is run at client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Comment: echo a function in the script tag, and at the bottom of the page call for that function. However, then you should echo something else when `$model` is not null or... if you don't care about the error log, don't. You can also use the [jquery document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

Comment: That's not jquery, that is javascript..

Comment: I think you certainly have to read [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I was expecting this comment from someone.

Answer (score 0):

Was working on a recent project to execute JavaScript after PHP was finished executing. Try placing the script tag after the PHP tag:

test.php:

```
<?php
    echo "hello";
    include("example.html") // To insert HTML page
?>
<script>
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

Comment: What if the OP wanted to run the `<script>` in an IF condition?

Comment: I used a PHP boolean variable then echoed that valued to a hidden input field. Called it in the <script>, then processed client side. Pass JSON data this way using json_encoded and JSON.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You can try it. I forced $model to be null.

```
<?php
    $model = null;
    if(is_null($model)) {
        echo "<script>alert('Hello World')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Seriously ! ! It still didn't work for me . . Am I missing anything ? ?

Comment: You just copy pasted this or did some tweeking?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call close from client Javascript from server PHP.
but you can call from HTML client.  put close in bottom of HTML body tag
and make sure Javascript is turned on in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are executing a `query` and then checking if result is `null` then this `script` to run then please correct. `PHP` `is_null` is `true` when it get `NULL` `php` `datatype` and a `query` never returns this. So if i am right then you can use this one this is my example which i used to check your method.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user") or die("error");
$res = mysqli_query($con, "select * from user where id =-99");
$model = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if(empty($model)) {
            echo "<script>window.parent.closeIframe(true)</script>";
        }
    ?>
```

just to check you can refer

```
$model = 0;
 <?php
        if(empty($model)) {
            echo "<script>alert("hello")</script>";
        }
    ?>
```