# calling javascript function from PHP after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm trying to call a javascript function after form submit and having any error then i want this script to run but this code is not working.I'm new in PHP Please help

```
 if(!empty($varAccountType))
{
<?php  
  if($varAccountType=='Free Account')
   {  
     echo "inside $varAccountType";  //this line is working
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">OnSelectionAcctType(Free Account);</script>';  
  //only this is not calling//
   } 
?>}
```

please help..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you try by passing like below    echo '<script type="text/javascript">OnSelectionAcctType("Free Account");</script>';

Comment: thanks @VenkateshKonatham it's working now :) 

thank you very much

Comment: You could also just end the PHP code and then put the javascript in normally then start the PHP code again..

Comment: Welcome. I have added it in the below. Please mark it as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

can you try by passing like below

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">OnSelectionAcctType("Free Account");</script>';
```