# PHP echo html table error

Tags: php, html, html-table, echo

I have created a table using data from a database, to create it I used a loop to get every piece of data from the columns I need. Now, I have called a `javascript` function in the `HTML` `onClick` of the input. But, I keep getting an error. The function does seem to work, It's just the actual `echo` that seems to be giving the error. It's on line 58 where you can see I am creating a table and inserting the rows.

**UPDATE**

My javascript function is working. The error is when it tries to set the `<td>` width and alignment.
The error I get is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    $deny = array("222.222.222", "333.333.333");
    if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
       header("location: http://www.google.com/");
       exit();
    }
    $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.py69.esy.es"); ?>
    <head>
        <title>ServiceCoin</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/home/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">ServiceCoin.com(image)</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php?logout" class="a">Sign Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Get Service Coins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.php" class="a">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Referrals</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php" class="a">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.php" class="a">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br /><br />
        <center>
        <h3>Welcome, <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?>. You Currently Have <span id="services"><?php echo $userRow['userServices']; ?></span> Services</h3>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <button onclick="send_coins()" class="button">Send Coins</button>
        <button onclick="create_service()" class="button">Create A Service</button>
        <button onclick="send_coins()" class="button">My Services</button>
        <h3>View Services</h3>
        <span><?php 
        $users = 1;
        $num = 1;
        echo "<center><table width=1000><th>Buy</th><th>Service Name</th><th>Service Cost</th><th>Service Description</th><th>Service Provider Name</th>";
        while($users < 100 && $num < 100){
            $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$users);
            $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
            $id = 0;
            while($id != 10){
                $id = $id + 1;
                if($userRow['userService'.$id] === 'null'){
                }else if(!empty($userRow['userService'.$id])){
                echo "<tr class=services ><td name=".$num."><input type=submit onClick='buy(".$userRow['userService'.$id].",".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id].",".$userRow['userServiceEmail'].")'></td><td width='250' align='center'>".$userRow['userService'.$id]."</td><td width='250' align='center'>".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id]."</td><td width='250' align='center'>".$userRow['userServiceDes'.$id]."</td><td width='250' align='center'>".$userRow['userServiceName'.$id]."</td></tr>";  

                //echo $id."Error: ".$con->error;           
                $num = $num + 1;
                }
            }
            $users = $users + 1;
        }
        echo "All Services Loaded";
        echo "</table></center>";
        ?></span>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $msg; ?></span>
        </center>
    </body>
    <script lang="text/javascript" src="scripts/home/index.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">


function buy(sid, scost, semail){
    console.log(sid,scost,semail);
}

</script>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Comment: Look at the edit please

Comment: `<td width='250' align='center'>"` place single quotes as shown, see if that helps.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be working. I still get the same error. I will put it in the question

Comment: can you please post this line echo "<tr class=services ><td name=$num<input type=submit onClick=buy(".$userRow['userService'.$id].",".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id].",".$userRow['userServiceEmail'].")>Buy</td><td width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userService'.$id]."</td><td width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id]."</td><td class=services width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceDes'.$id]."<td width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceName'.$id]."</tr>";  of code in HTML by inspect element? @morgan

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: may not be related, but you also seem to be incrementing your "id" variable twice per while loop, which is kind of weird.

Comment: Yeah thank you didn't see that

Comment: Your onClick argument should be contained in quotes. As should all of your other tag attributes such as class and name. The onClick not being quoted is almost certainly why you are seeing the JS error

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to affect it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, you need to use quotes for all attributes and JS calls. Additionally, rembember that the contents of your onClick must be valid JS. As such, the strings you are passing as arguments to the function should be in quotes.

`echo '<tr class="services"><td name="'.$num.'"><input type="submit" onClick="buy(\''.$userRow['userService'.$id].'\',\''.$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id].'\',\''.$userRow['userServiceEmail'].'\')"></td><td width="250" align="center">'.$userRow['userService'.$id].'</td><td width="250" align="center">'.$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id].'</td><td width="250" align="center">'.$userRow['userServiceDes'.$id].'</td><td width="250" align="center">'.$userRow['userServiceName'.$id].'</td></tr>';`

Comment: Yeah sorry i noticed that and forgot to update the code on here. Sorry, that didn't fix it