# Javascript function in php doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a php function which ends with a refresh of the page and then throws a javascript function declared:

```
<script>
    var u = null;
    function tab(u) {
        $('#element1').css('display', 'block');
        $('#element2').css('display', 'none');
    }
</script>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $tab = 1;
        header("Refresh:0");            
        echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0, 1000);</script>";
        echo "<script>tab(".$tab.");</script>";
    }
?>
```

The function of window.scrollto works, but the tab function not.
I wrote ob_start and ob_end_flush to avoid headers problems.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: there might be a problem because you are using `header` function after generating an output...

Comment: No, I don't get errors in javascript console and php errors

Comment: I wrote ob_start and ob_end_flush to avoid headers problems

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php

Comment: What happens if you set the PHP $tab variable explicitly to a string: `$tab = "1";` (That is, to a PHP string. It will still be an integer to JavaScript.) Also, can you paste in the JavaScript that gets generated?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `)` on the if statement. Try this:

```
  <script>
    var u = null;
    function tab(u) {
        $('#element1').css('display', 'block');
        $('#element2').css('display', 'none');
    }
</script>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $tab = 1;
        header("Refresh:0");            
        echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0, 1000);</script>";
        echo "<script>tab(".$tab.");</script>";
    }
?>
```

The `header("Refresh:0");` shoudn't be a problem as you said. In the worst case you will get an warning saying `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`.

Also, in development you should always have `error_reporting` turned on to be able to see the possible errors or warnings. You can turn on error reporting like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Don't forget to remove/comment that on production/live.

Comment: Good catch!. Should it not throw error on server side?

Comment: I have it like this but writing the question I made a mistake.

Comment: @SandeepNayak, it should have if he had the error reporting turned on.

Comment: @GerryStudios, let me check it again.

Comment: I've erased the header("Refresh:0") because I saw I don't need it and now it works, thanks.