# Can't call a JavaScript function on a php script

Tags: javascript, getjson

When I called the javascript function within the php script, it just called `run()` but not the function of the `run()`. Is there something wrong on my JavaScript or php script?

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

    function run(){
        $.getJSON("http://smartfypwindow.000webhostapp.com/api/led/update.php?id=1&status=Close", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
</script>

<?php

    $dbusername = "id3137057_windowdatabase"; 

    $dbpassword = "root123";  

    $server = "localhost"; 

    $My_db = "id3137057_window";

    // Connect to your database

    $dbconnect = mysqli_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);

    $dbselect = mysqli_select_db($dbconnect,"id3137057_window");

    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT temp, hum, lum FROM 
    weather");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        if($row["temp"] < 27) {
            echo" run()";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($dbconnect);

?>
```

Comment: You should also echo `<script>` before `run()` and `</script>` after it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go this approach...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    if($row["temp"] < 27) {
        echo" <script>run()</script>";
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: After apply this, i get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at run.

Comment: Problem solved. Actually, i forgot to load the jquery.