# How to call ajax from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to run an ajax function from php like below? I know i can do it the other way but this would be the best way to do what i want i think.

Im trying to load a specific page based on some variables in php.

```
  <?php
     runFunction();
  ?>
  <script>
     function runFunction() {
        $.ajax({
           // do stuff?
        });
     }
  </script>
```

I have already tried the above and i've tried just putting the ajax in php... but everything i find on the old google just comes up php from ajax not the other way around.

thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't run JS functions from PHP, there is cUrl for PHP

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser while PHP runs on the server. Can't you just output the content of that function if you want to run it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do it on JS event document.ready

```
<html>
  <script>
     function runFunction() {
        $.ajax({
           // do stuff?
        });
     }
  </script>
<?php
     echo "<body onload='runFunction()'></body>";
?>
</html>
```