# Trigger JS Function on HTML Page from PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, call

my problem is as following:

I have two files. Let's call them form.html and handler.php

As you may expected the html file is an email form and the php file is there to send it.

Now i want to trigger an BS4 alert on the html file from the php file when the mail is successfully sent or not.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     <strong>Whoops!</strong>Something went wrong there.. Please try again!
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     <strong>Success!</strong>Mail successfully delivered. I will be in touch with you shortly!
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

The php code part that should be triggering the alert later is linking to a defined page at the moment.

```
if($mail_senden){
    header("Location: ".$url_ok); //Fehler beim Senden
    exit();
} else{
    header("Location: ".$url_fehler); //Fehler beim Senden
    exit();
}
```

Any ideas?

And maybe i should mention that i'm familiar with bootstrap but my knowledge in js and php is very limited (#scriptkidlifestyle)

Comment: You can inject JS code into the page you're serving, so what's your question?

Comment: And how can i do that? As i've written, i have absolutely no clue about JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to display an alert :

```
<script>
if (mail_sent) {
    alert("Mail sent !");
    }

else{
    alert("Mail not sent");
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, that's not what i wanted to do because the php file and the HTML are 2 Files and i want to display the Alarm on the HTML page.

Comment: Hem... Yes, i guess your PHP file and your HTML file are 2 files. But you Can include a js file with the <script> tag, and the PHP file with an include.

Comment: Yeah but what would that do? I guess you did not get the question right. I want to trigger an alert on a HTML file from a separate php file using js..